# Calcular Meses entre de un campo Fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

tengo el siguiente query super basico

```
SELECT
t.NOperacion, t.Fecha
FROM Tabla t
Where t.NOperacion = 4548764
```

que me arroja este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero otro campo que me calcule cuantos meses hay desde el primer registro de fecha hasta la ultima

este es el resultado que quiero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Para eso caso puedes realizar una sub consulta en sql, donde tomas el ultimo registro y lo comparas con el primero para ver cuanto tiempo transcurrio, en sql no sabria decirte con exactitud la funcion, pero por alli va la cosa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto te puede servir:

```sql
select t.NOperacion operacion, 
       t.fecha,
       cast(datediff(month,
            first_value(t.fecha) over(order by t.NOperacion),
            last_value(t.fecha) over(order by t.NOperacion))
       as varchar(2)) + ' meses' as meses
from Tabla t
where t.NOperacion = 4548764
```

El resultado sería algo parecido a esto:

```sql
+-----------+------------+---------+
| operacion | fecha      | meses   | 
+-----------+------------+---------+
| 4548764   | 01/01/2022 | 4 meses |
| 4548764   | 01/02/2022 | 4 meses |
| 4548764   | 01/03/2022 | 4 meses |
| 4548764   | 01/04/2022 | 4 meses |
| 4548764   | 01/05/2022 | 4 meses |
+-----------+------------+---------+
```

Te debería resultar normal haciendo uso del <kbd>**DATEDIFF**</kbd>, sin embargo depende de la configuración del <kbd>**COLLATE**</kbd>, hice pruebas con otro distinto al de Latin y SQL Server toma como mes el valor 1 y por tanto la resta te dará 0 (meses) siempre.

---

##### UPDATE:

El tema con el uso de <kbd>**FIRST_VALUE**</kbd> y el <kbd>**LAST_VALUE**</kbd> tal como está ahora es que funciona bien por el hecho de tener ese <kbd>**WHERE**</kbd>, en caso que quieras hacerlo para todos los registros, pero aún así tener la diferencia del primero y el último valor de la fecha POR operación, la consulta quedaría así:

```sql
select t.NOperacion operacion, 
       t.fecha,
       cast(datediff(month,
        first_value(t.fecha) over(partition by t.NOperacion order by t.NOperacion),
        last_value(t.fecha) over(partition by t.NOperacion order by t.NOperacion))
       as varchar(2)) + ' meses' as meses
from Tabla t
```